# The Partition problem

Tags: algorithm

I have set of non-unique numbers and would like to partition those numbers into `K` partitions such that sum of numbers in each partition is almost equal  .
Assume I have following set.

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Using [Linear partition algorithm](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK2/NODE45.HTM#SECTION02312000000000000000) I get following partitions when `K = 3`

```
{ 1  2  3  4  5 }
{ 6  7 }
{ 8  9 }
```

Which is expected, but since this is linear partitioning algorithm , any change in the order of the input set will change the partitions also, which I want to avoid.

Difference of Sum of elements for each partition should be minimized. In above example Sum of each partitions is `15` , `13`, `17`

for following input it does not work.

```
{10, 20, 90, 100, 200}
```

Linear partition algorithm gives me following

```
{ 10  20  90  100 }
{ 200 }
```

But correct answer should be

`{ 10, 200 }
 { 20, 90, 100 }`

Comment: So you want to partition them regardless of the order in the “set”?

Comment: step one - re-order the set, step two - perform the working partition

Comment: @svick, Yes, in other words which will always give me same set of partitions when the input is same and numbers of partitions are same , regardless of how the input numbers are arranges.

Comment: @Avinash, what exactly do you mean by “almost equal”? What are the exact requirements? Do you need to find the best solution?

Comment: @svick, I will update the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a fast greedy solution (near-optimal for most cases):

1. Sort the elements in descending order
2. Take the first `K` elements and put them into different sets
3. For the next `N-K` elements, put them in the set with the lowest sum

In your case with `{10, 20, 90, 100, 200}`, after sorting you get `{200, 100, 90, 20, 10}`. The algorithm will step through as follows:

```
Set A   Set B
 200     100
 200     190
 200     210
 210     210
```

which happens to be the optimal solution.

Comment: your step 2 is for clarification, because step 3 includes it. great job

Comment: great solution..is this known algorithm or yours.

Comment: Given the set `{3, 3, 2, 2, 2}` with `K=2`, this algorithm partitions it into `{3,2,2}`, `{3,2}` whereas the optimal solution is `{3,3}`,`{2,2,2}`.

Comment: How would I prove the correctness of this algorithm? I mean, if the list wasn't sorted or sorted in ascending order, this will fail. I'm not able to prove this algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I think that pretty much the only option you have is to use brute force, possibly with some optimizations (like a modified version of [the pseudo-polynomial solution to subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) for `K = 2`) for simple cases. Maybe there is a better algorithm, but not much better.

From reading the Wikipedia articles on [Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) and [3-partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem), I get that your problem is generalized and slightly modified version of these problems, that are NP-complete.

More specifically, if you had an efficient algorithm for solving your problem, it would also be able to efficiently solve the two problems above, which is impossible (unless P = NP).

Comment: Dynamic programming could be useful here, and will be better than brute force. I don't know enough to write an answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it working in general and you're just looking for deterministic behaviour regardless of the order, just sort the set first.  All sets that are the same disregarding order will be the exact same sequence after being sorted.

Of course it might inflate your runtime complexity but I didn't see that preventing this was a requirement.

All this is based on your comment that the arrangement of numbers truly doesn't matter.  At that point this certainly isn't the same as the problem you linked to, which assumes that the partitions never require rearranging the elements.

Answer (score 0):

[LeetCoder have worked](http://www.leetcode.com/2011/04/the-painters-partition-problem.html) on the same problem definition (and solution) provided by Steven Skiena. Only thing is that he talks in C++, so it becomes some what easier to grasp.