# Add batch number to DataFrame based on moving sum in spark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset that I need to process batchwise (due to API restrictions).

**The sum of the column text_lenth of a batch cannot exceed 1000**. And the maximum **number of rows in a batch cannot be greater than 5**.

For that I would like to add batch numbers to the single batches in order to process the data based on batch_numbers later.

How can I achieve that in pyspark (in Databricks). I am pretty new to all of this that I don't even know what to look for online.

I really appreciate your help.

The tables below illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

Original table

| id | text_length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 300 |
| 5 | 100 |
| 6 | 100 |
| 7 | 100 |
| 8 | 100 |
| 9 | 100 |
| 10 | 300 |

Resulting table

| id | text_length | batch_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 1 |
| 2 | 400 | 1 |
| 3 | 200 | 2 |
| 4 | 300 | 2 |
| 5 | 100 | 2 |
| 6 | 100 | 2 |
| 7 | 100 | 2 |
| 8 | 100 | 3 |
| 9 | 100 | 3 |
| 10 | 300 | 3 |

Comment: FYI it's called the [partition problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669460/the-partition-problem)

Comment: Are the ids guranteed to be unique and consecutively numbered? And does the actual value of the batch_number matter or could the batch_numbers be random as long as they are unique?

Comment: not really solvable with spark unless you code round partition boundaries. i have one so answer on that but elaborate.

Comment: @werner the ids are unique, but random. The batch_numbers can be random of course.

Comment: I am pretty sure my view point is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not looking for the optimal solution but for a way to solve the problem in Spark without too much complexity, we can divide the problem into two steps:

1. split the data in blocks with 5 rows each, ignoring the text length
2. if the sum of the text lenghts in one block is too large, split this block into further blocks

This solution is not optimal as it produces too many batches.

Step 1 can be implemented using [zipWithIndex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex.html#pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex). When creating the batch ids, we leave enough "space" for dividing the batches later. At the end of this step all rows in one block are grouped into a single list as input for step 2:

```python
df = ...

r = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF() \
    .select("_1.id", "_1.text_length", "_2") \
    .withColumn("batch", F.expr("cast(_2 / 5 as long)*5")) \
    .withColumn("data", F.struct("id", "text_length", "batch")) \
    .groupBy("batch") \
    .agg(F.collect_list("data").alias("data"))
```

Part 2 consists mainly of an [udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html) that checks if within one batch the maximum text length is exceeded. If so, the batch id for the following elements is increased by one. As we have skipped enough batch ids in part 1, we do not get any collisions.

```python
def splitBatchIfNecessary(data):
    text_length = 0
    batch = -1
    for d in data:
        text_length = text_length + d.text_length
        if text_length > 1000:
          if batch == -1:
            text_length = 0
            batch = d.batch + 1
            yield (d.id, d.text_length, d.batch)
          else:
            text_length = d.text_length
            batch = batch + 1
            yield (d.id, d.text_length, batch)          
        else:
          if batch == -1:
            batch = d.batch
          yield (d.id, d.text_length, batch)

schema=r.schema["data"].dataType
split_udf = F.udf(splitBatchIfNecessary, schema)

r = r.withColumn("data",split_udf(F.col("data")) ) \
      .selectExpr("explode(data)") \
      .select("col.*")
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------+-----+                                                         
| id|text_length|batch|
+---+-----------+-----+
|  1|        500|    0|
|  2|        400|    0|
|  3|        200|    1|
|  4|        300|    1|
|  5|        100|    1|
|  6|        100|    5|
|  7|        100|    5|
|  8|        100|    5|
|  9|        100|    5|
| 10|        300|    5|
+---+-----------+-----+
```

Possible optimizations would be to replace `zipWithIndex` by [zipWithUniqueIds](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.zipWithUniqueId.html#pyspark.RDD.zipWithUniqueId) (but getting slightly more "incomplete" batches) or using a [vectorized udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html#pandas-udfs-a-k-a-vectorized-udfs).

Comment: @thebluephantom I did not find any issues, also not with larger datasets. Did you spot any? As long as the cluster is able to handle the `zipWithIndex`, it will work. Step 2 is a plain vanilla groupBy that won't cause any troubles.

Comment: Nice one. Saving grace is the 5 limit and no negative numbers = Upvote. And zipWithIndex.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure it works. Try this as input:         (1,200),
        (2,600),
        (3,800),
        (4,1),
        (5,1),
        (6,1), 
        (14,1),
        (115,1),
        (114,1),
        (225,1),
        (7,1)

Comment: In fact the outcome is not correct as per spec.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's what I meant with "This solution is not optimal as it produces too many batches." In theory, batch 1 and 5 should be merged, but my code cannot do that.

Comment: OK, but then it is not an answer according to the question. I am leaving the upvote because it shows good thinking. I thought you got around the partition boundaries with this approach but not so, the approximation is just that.

Comment: @werner I like this solution. Although it is not the most efficient, it is a good balance between complexity and efficiency. And way better than processing each entry separately.

Comment: @thebluephantom you sample input is actually pretty realistic in my dataset. I will try if shuffling the data is helping. Maybe this would prevent very low consecutive text_lengths.

Comment: The point is that the question states this and not that. The answer may be a compromise, but my answer addresses the primary question.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike mck states, this is not the "partition problem".

What the issues are, are that 1) Spark works with partitions - not just 1 such partition in order to be effective and 2) there is not a grouping attribute to ensure that 'batches' can form naturally or be distilled naturally within a partition *only*. Moreover, can we have negative numbers or fractions? - this is not stated. Max 5 entries it is stated, however.

1. This means that processing would need to be just based on one partition, but it may not be big enough aka OOM.
2. Trying to process per partition is pointless as all work would need to be done per partition N, N+1, and so on die to offset effects in the partition N-1. I have worked out a solution here on SO that took partition boundaries into account, but this is against the principle of Spark and the use case was more simplistic.
3. *Actually not a Spark use case. It is a sequential algorithm as opposed to parallel algorithm, use PL/SQL, Scala, JAVA, C++.*
4. The only way would be:

   - looping over a fixed size partition that has had zipWithIndex applied globally (for safety)

     - process with Scala into batches - temp result
     - take all items from last created batch and union with next partition
     - remove last batch from temp results
     - repeat cycle
5. NB: Approximations to get around partitioning boundary aspects of data seem not to work --> the other answer proves that in fact. You get a compromise result, not the actually answer. And to correct it is not on fact that easy as batches have gaps and may be in other partitions as result of grouping.